# Generate number repeating python

Tags: python, random, repeat, generate

Code:

```
import random
number1=random.randint(0,62)
print(number1)
```

I tried and the numbers repeated each other.

One condition: The numbers will be different.

Comment: add context, did you do it in loop or somenthing

Comment: It's not random if the numbers don't repeat. I think you are looking for a random *ordering* of the numbers from 1 to n.

Comment: numbers should be different when code is written.

Comment: The numbers will be different if you rerun lines 2 and 3.  Were you just printing again and expecting a different value?

Comment: Please note tht `random.randint(0,62)` generates a single value, between the given range 0 and 62, i think what your looking for is `random.sample()`

Comment: I want to create different values ​​when I run it again @pjs

Comment: You need to provide more details -- run it again *how*?  What you've provided generates one value, so the concept of a repeated value is meaningless unless you give the details of what you ran to produce the repeat.  As written, your problem is not reproducible which is why I've voted to close it.

Comment: Let the numbers in the range of values ​​I enter every time I run the code. without repeating each other

Comment: What you've written above produces one value, so there cannot be a repeat produced by your code fragment.  Show us what you actually did that produces repeated numbers.

Comment: no need, thanks broo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. The `sample` method can be used to generate set of unique numbers using random module :)

```
import random
number1 = random.sample(range(1, 62), 61)
print(number1)
```

Comment: number1=random.randint(0,62,62)
TypeError: randint() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given. error..

Comment: thank you, can we do it by showing the code one by one rather than collectively?

Comment: You will need 50+ lines of code for it or do u want to loop over it ? This is a efficient way to do this tho

Comment: I want to write in a loop without repeating each other.

Comment: im adding it as a seperate answer here

Comment: i am waiting for you